SUSE SLE Micro - Setup STA + p2p-go on Raspberry pi 4 Model B to connect Android using Wifi direct
I would like to setup my pi with station and p2p-go and want to connect Android Samsung to PI using WiFi Direct which is able to connect with my printer WIFI direct with simple connect so no problem with phone. My operating system is SUSE SLE micro. I have spend really good amount of time following lots of threads but no luck. The close i got to the solution was my PI device appear in the list of WIFI Direct of the phone but when trying to connect either it asks PIN which I gave (I have generated through WPS_PIN ANY) but no luck, error says "can't validate interface -16 or sometimes -52.
Here are all the details and i am looking for steps as don't understand why it's not working. I don't want PIN or anything, just click and it should connect.
Operating System Info
---------------------
NAME="SL-Micro"
VERSION="6.0"
VERSION_ID="6.0"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Micro 6.0"
ID="sl-micro"
ID_LIKE="suse"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sl-micro:6.0"
HOME_URL="https://www.suse.com/products/micro/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://documentation.suse.com/sl-micro/6.0/"

iw dev
-------
phy#0
        Unnamed/non-netdev interface
                wdev 0x3
                addr da:3a:dd:31:12:00
                type P2P-device
                txpower 31.00 dBm
        Interface wlan0
                ifindex 3
                wdev 0x1
                addr d8:3a:dd:31:12:00
                ssid home_network
                type managed
                channel 153 (5765 MHz), width: 80 MHz, center1: 5775 MHz
                txpower 31.00 dBm


cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
---------------------------------------------
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
device_name=DIRECT_PI
device_type=6-0050F204-1
driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1
p2p_go_intent=7
country=US
ap_scan=1
p2p_disabled=0
p2p_go_ht40=1


iw list
-------------------
Wiphy phy0
        wiphy index: 0
        max # scan SSIDs: 10
        max scan IEs length: 2048 bytes
        max # sched scan SSIDs: 16
        max # match sets: 16
        Retry short limit: 7
        Retry long limit: 4
        Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
        Device supports roaming.
        Supported Ciphers:
                * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
                * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
                * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
                * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
                * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
        Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
        Supported interface modes:
                 * IBSS
                 * managed
                 * AP
                 * P2P-client
                 * P2P-GO
                 * P2P-device
        Band 1:
                Capabilities: 0x1022
                        HT20/HT40
                        Static SM Power Save
                        RX HT20 SGI
                        No RX STBC
                        Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                        DSSS/CCK HT40
                Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
                Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
                HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7
                Bitrates (non-HT):
                        * 1.0 Mbps
                        * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 6.0 Mbps
                        * 9.0 Mbps
                        * 12.0 Mbps
                        * 18.0 Mbps
                        * 24.0 Mbps
                        * 36.0 Mbps
                        * 48.0 Mbps
                        * 54.0 Mbps
                Frequencies:
                        * 2412.0 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2417.0 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2422.0 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2427.0 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2432.0 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2437.0 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2442.0 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2447.0 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2452.0 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2457.0 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2462.0 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2467.0 MHz [12] (disabled)
                        * 2472.0 MHz [13] (disabled)
                        * 2484.0 MHz [14] (disabled)
        Band 2:
                Capabilities: 0x1062
                        HT20/HT40
                        Static SM Power Save
                        RX HT20 SGI
                        RX HT40 SGI
                        No RX STBC
                        Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                        DSSS/CCK HT40
                Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
                Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
                HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7
                VHT Capabilities (0x00001020):
                        Max MPDU length: 3895
                        Supported Channel Width: neither 160 nor 80+80
                        short GI (80 MHz)
                        SU Beamformee
                VHT RX MCS set:
                        1 streams: MCS 0-9
                        2 streams: not supported
                        3 streams: not supported
                        4 streams: not supported
                        5 streams: not supported
                        6 streams: not supported
                        7 streams: not supported
                        8 streams: not supported
                VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
                VHT TX MCS set:
                        1 streams: MCS 0-9
                        2 streams: not supported
                        3 streams: not supported
                        4 streams: not supported
                        5 streams: not supported
                        6 streams: not supported
                        7 streams: not supported
                        8 streams: not supported
                VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
                VHT extended NSS: not supported
                Bitrates (non-HT):
                        * 6.0 Mbps
                        * 9.0 Mbps
                        * 12.0 Mbps
                        * 18.0 Mbps
                        * 24.0 Mbps
                        * 36.0 Mbps
                        * 48.0 Mbps
                        * 54.0 Mbps
                Frequencies:
                        * 5170.0 MHz [34] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5180.0 MHz [36] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5190.0 MHz [38] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5200.0 MHz [40] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5210.0 MHz [42] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5220.0 MHz [44] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5230.0 MHz [46] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5240.0 MHz [48] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5260.0 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
                        * 5280.0 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
                        * 5300.0 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
                        * 5320.0 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
                        * 5500.0 MHz [100] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
                        * 5520.0 MHz [104] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
                        * 5540.0 MHz [108] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
                        * 5560.0 MHz [112] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
                        * 5580.0 MHz [116] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
                        * 5600.0 MHz [120] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
                        * 5620.0 MHz [124] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
                        * 5640.0 MHz [128] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
                        * 5660.0 MHz [132] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
                        * 5680.0 MHz [136] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
                        * 5700.0 MHz [140] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
                        * 5720.0 MHz [144] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
                        * 5745.0 MHz [149] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5765.0 MHz [153] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5785.0 MHz [157] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5805.0 MHz [161] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5825.0 MHz [165] (20.0 dBm)
        Supported commands:
                 * new_interface
                 * set_interface
                 * new_key
                 * start_ap
                 * join_ibss
                 * set_pmksa
                 * del_pmksa
                 * flush_pmksa
                 * remain_on_channel
                 * frame
                 * set_wiphy_netns
                 * set_channel
                 * start_sched_scan
                 * start_p2p_device
                 * connect
                 * disconnect
                 * crit_protocol_start
                 * crit_protocol_stop
                 * update_connect_params
        software interface modes (can always be added):
        valid interface combinations:
                 * #{ managed } <= 2, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
                   total <= 3, #channels <= 2
                 * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
                   total <= 4, #channels <= 1
        Device supports scan flush.
        Device supports randomizing MAC-addr in sched scans.
        max # scan plans: 1
        max scan plan interval: 508
        max scan plan iterations: 0
        Supported TX frame types:
                 * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
        Supported RX frame types:
                 * managed: 0x40 0xd0
                 * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
                 * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
        Supported extended features:
                * [ CQM_RSSI_LIST ]: multiple CQM_RSSI_THOLD records
                * [ 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_STA_PSK ]: 4-way handshake with PSK in station mode
                * [ 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_STA_1X ]: 4-way handshake with 802.1X in station mode
                * [ DFS_OFFLOAD ]: DFS offload
                * [ SAE_OFFLOAD ]: SAE offload support
                * [ 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_AP_PSK ]: AP mode PSK offload support
                * [ SAE_OFFLOAD_AP ]: AP mode SAE authentication offload support

wpa_cli interface
-------------------
Selected interface 'wlan0'
Available interfaces:
p2p-dev-wlan0
wlan0


Sometimes I am able to add p2p_group_add but sometimes it failed, so I don't know at what point need to do what. I am using wpa_cli.
Let me know any more information required
NOTE;- THIS IS SUSE SLE Micro. I have installed iw, hostapd and it has dnsmqs and wpa_supplicant but don't have dhcp or systemd-networkd.
